# How can I tell whether a web app was built using Angular (or other technologies)?

Tags: angularjs, drupal

How can I tell whether a (Drupal 7) web app was built using Angular by looking at the page source, and not having to ask the developers?

Comment: Try opening the console and typing `window.angular.version`

Answer (score 41):

[image]The best way to check is to write "angular" on browser console. If you get any object [With child objects as "bind","bootstrap","callbacks","module" etc.] then its an angular web app.

Comment: I add an picture you can write angular in console and click on the triangle you can find the child objects there

Comment: In angular 4, now we can't access angular object in console. so need to find another fix.

Comment: You actually can't access angular object in console for Angular 2+

Comment: Run this in angular 2+ :  window.getAngularTestability

Comment: this is not the case , this site was made on angular 8 but no luck  https://akveo.com/ngx-admin/pages/dashboard

Answer (score 21):

You can install a chrome or firefox extension called [Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/). It tells you which site you are navigated on in your browser and the stack they use.

Find it here: [https://www.wappalyzer.com](https://www.wappalyzer.com/)

Comment: Unfortunately for me, it often shows Express web framework instead of Angular. I also have a website written in Python Flask and Wappalyzer does not recognize it.

Comment: the link is dead.

Comment: @igsm mostly because flask is a backend framework, it does most of the processing behind the back and does not include any specific clues (such as flask-related comments) on the rendered website, whereas it is easy to identify other frameworks like react (has a virtual DOM), or angular (has `ng` attributes spread all across).

Answer (score 19):

You could try: `angular.version.full` first. If this doesn't work, try `getAllAngularRootElements()[0].attributes["ng-version"]`. The reason being in Angular 1 the former will work and from angular 2 onwards the later will work.

Comment: This works for me `getAllAngularRootElements()[0].attributes["ng-version"]`. Thanks !

Answer (score 9):

If it's an online site you can use http://builtwith.com/ and it usually can give you a good and useful bunch of information about that site.

However if they are using angular you can take a look at their page sources to see if they are using any attributes of angular like `ng-repeat` for example

You can also take a look at the sources that your browser get while browsing that site to see if `javascript` files for `angularjs` are included among the sources.

Answer (score 4):

- Application declared using ng-app directive
- very simple controller and directive
- check for ng-model, ng-repeater attributes in the code. All these attibutes are written in small letters.
- Also you can check by typing in the console(ctrl + shift + i) and navigate to console tab. There type in window.angular.version --> it displays the version of the site your are currently inspecting.

Comment: This was worked for me window.getAllAngularRootElements()

Answer (score 4):

For Angular, in Chrome's inspector, in the Elements tab, inside the body element is an element called `app-root` containing `ng-version`, which shows the Angular version it's using.

Answer (score 3):

Try

https://builtwith.com/

This is the website that currently gives you the most detailed information about what technologies a site uses. They will let you do 5 free lookups a day.

https://wappalyzer.com/

is a good one too, and serve as a complement to builtwith. I don't think there is a limit of lookups, but the results are less detailed.

Those two used together may give you more insight.

Answer (score 3):

Use `window.getAllAngularRootElements()` in the browser console, if it returns some value, it's an `angular` application.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Google Chrome extension called 'ng-detector'. It may be obtained from the Google webstore:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-detector/fedicaemhcfcmelihceehhaodggfeffm

It creates a small icon next to the URL bar that indicates whether or not it thinks the page was created using Angular, although I have not thoroughly tested its validity.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a Chrome or Firefox extension called [Augury](https://augury.rangle.io/). It tells you if app is an angular or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

window.getAllAngularRootElements() worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Install chrome extension React-Detector, it works!