# Remove the loading spinner in google chrome tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, spinner

I am trying to make a website for my project. While surfing for some "cool" ideas, I stumbled upon https://www.fliplingo.com/. On this website, when you click on any tab, the icon of the website in the chrome tab does not change to the spinner icon. Instead there is a progress bar and a spinner on top of the page itself. How exactly do i go about doing this?

Comment: This type of website is known as a 'Single Page Application'. It gets all its content via AJAX requests. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: @Databases. Did my answer provide you the information requested. I gave you exact solution the example used as well as jquery one for use in your own project. Please mark it as correct or supply your own answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact site implemention of the spinner is done with ng-progress / angular SPA. You can see that when they page is loading the ng-progress-busy class is added to the html tag.

http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/

Another Solution if you just want the Progress bar without Angular to use on an AJAX call or page load with you can use NProgress https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress This is what the NgProgress was based from

An example for slim progress bars like on YouTube, Medium, etc http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress

Comment: You seem to be making the assumption that the OP is using Angular

Comment: Yes and when I see the class being added is "ng-progress-busy" my assumption is closer to a fact versus an assumption. That and if you inspect the site and type angular it returns the angular object:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950213/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-web-app-was-built-using-angular

Comment: @Enkode - you seem to have answered a question which was not asked, namely "How does fliplingo do it", when the question asked was "How exactly do I go about doing this", for which there a variety of correct answers. Using Angular is just one of those. That's an awfully heavy framework just to show a spinner and to fetch new content. I.e it's 39.5kb, when the effect may be achieved in less than a few hundred bytes. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep I submitted an answer which explained to him the exact control and framework used to create the desired effect. If you have a solution that can be achieved in less than a few hundred bytes I recommend you submit an answer instead of trolling mine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer, it's much better in my opinion than it was when I made that comment. My comment was in response to the imprecise way you answered and the prickly response you gave to Rory. You and I clearly have very different working definitions of the word trolling, let's simply leave it at that. Your answer is a good one. Just (continue to) relax mate.