# Can not run protractor tests with headless chrome

Tags: protractor, google-chrome-headless

Some time ago google [announced that headless chrome is available in newest chrome versions](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai).
[Over there](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#using-headless-chrome) we can find config for headless chrome with protractor.

When I'm trying to run my test suite with `directConnect` - everything works as a charm.
capabilities looks like that:

```
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--start-maximized']            
        }
    },
```

When I change `args` line to:

`args: ['--start-maximized', '--headless', '--disable-gpu']`

and run tests, I receive an error:

```
 E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page https://address.com/ : retries looking for angular exceeded
Unhandled rejection Error: Angular could not be found on the page https://address.com/.If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.
Please see 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load
    at executeAsyncScript_.then (/home/user/Projects/pef/tests/e2e/node_modules/protractor/lib/browser.ts:936:29)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/home/user/Projects/pef/tests/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/user/Projects/pef/tests/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/user/Projects/pef/tests/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
    at asyncRun (/home/user/Projects/pef/tests/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
    at /home/user/Projects/pef/tests/e2e/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Have anyone faced with this issue?

node: v8.4.0

npm: 5.3.0

chrome: 60.0.3112.113

protractor: 5.1.2

Comment: is it an angular app?

Comment: yes, it is [angular 2]

Comment: `directConnect: true` is still required. I have the same setup, it works.

Comment: @HaC I had `directConnect` flag set true. It's not a matter of that. I also tried to run a test with using `seleniumAddress` param. Same result.

Comment: I was able to repro the error when I changed my baseUrl to to https://address.com . It redirects to https://whitepages.com .  I was not able to run it on the regular (non headless) mode either. So I suspect that maybe it is not written in angular. Try this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950213/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-web-app-was-built-using-angular) to check if it is. Good luck!