# How does React Developer Tools determine that the webpage is using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

[I found this link for determining that a webpage is using angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950213/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-web-app-was-built-using-angular)

Tried doing the same thing for React, but there is no object displayed in console.

Any idea on how it works?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [react-devtools FAQ](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/b370497ba6e873c63479408f11d784095523a630#faq):

> When the page loads, the devtools sets a global named `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__`, then React communicates with that hook during initialization.

It appears others have found this as well, and someone asked how to prevent your production React app from working with React Devtools: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152804/368697